# Clip studio paint issue: "Unable to edit canvas because canvas contains data which cannot be used in this version"

Tags: painting, clip-studio-paint

I'm using clip studio paint 1.911 and this message pops ups when I open some clip documents:

"Unable to edit canvas because canvas contains data which cannot be used in this version"

How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE!  Can you share an example of what you are trying to open?

Comment: I've never used that software, so this is a guess. It's the kind of error message you can get in image editing software when opening an image created in a newer version of the software when trying to open it in an older version of the software. Basically the newer image file supports features that are not available in an older version of the software.